# How do I get cURL working over SSL with Phalanger?

Tags: php, ssl, curl, phalanger

I'm trying to use [Phalanger](https://github.com/DEVSENSE/Phalanger) to compile a script I wrote in PHP into a standalone executable. The script utilizes PHP's cURL extension to make various REST calls. This actually works fine so long as the websites it hits use **http**; however it fails any time I try to hit **https** endpoints.

I have tried adding this line into the PHP source:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

That would just ignore any SSL validation; however it doesn't work. It actually *does* work if I run the script in PHP, but when I compile it using Phalanger to an executable, it spits out this warning:

> Warning: curl_setopt(): Value 'False' of argument 'value' is not supported in C:\test.exe on line 76, column 2.

So, okay, that means I absolutely have to validate SSL? Sure, fine. So I found a [certificate store on cURL's website](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html), downloaded it, and changed my line above to the following:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, realpath(getcwd() . '/cacert.pem'));
```

Now when I compile it and run the executable, I get this warning instead:

> Value 'CURLOPT_CAINFO' of argument 'option' is not supported in C:\test.exe on line 77, column 2.

It seems I just can't win. How can I get cURL working through PHP compiled by Phalanger, over HTTPS?

Comment: This option has been disabled in Phalanger for performance reasons. Certificate should be added to windows certificates storage. See note on https://github.com/DEVSENSE/Phalanger/blob/8cdb36e81a7d6b1952bd054d52e6a8706a05d06b/Source/Extensions/Curl/UserDefined.cs#L1110